# Different colors for different environments with Weblogic 12c (12.2.1.4) web console

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I would like to use different colors on the WebLogic web console for different environments.
For example, I would like to use red for a production domain, green for DEV domain, etc.

Oracle calls it "Rebranding". I followed [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24966/rebrand.htm#CNSLX145) complicated instruction but it does not work for me. Maybe because my WebLogic version is newer.

I also followed [this](http://kaukovuo.blogspot.com/2015/04/changing-environment-warning-color-on.html) and [that](https://david-kerwick.github.io/2014-03-31-customise-skin-of-weblogic-admin-console/) docs, but they also did not work for me.

Is there any way to change the web console color somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css files are under $ORACLE_HOME/wls12213/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/webapp/framework/skins/wlsconsole/css/